# highlight nav item when user scrolls to a section

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've already posted something about this but I can't seem to find the solution. I'm trying to add a class to a certain a tag that's related to the section when user scrolls to the section. I tried this code below and nothing happens to the links.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var position  = $(this).scrollTop;

    $('.section').each(function() {
      var target = $(this).offset().top;
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var navLinks = $('#navigation li a');

      if(position >= target) { 
        navLinks.removeClass('current');
        $('#navigation li a[href^="#"' + id + ']').addClass('current');
      }
    });
   });
```

https://codepen.io/yubind/pen/OoOErZ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your anchor tag selection inside your scroll function and also in getting window offset. Use below code

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var position = window.pageYOffset;
   $('.section').each(function () {
     var target = $(this).offset().top;
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var navLinks = $('#navigation li a');
     if (position >= target) {
       navLinks.removeClass('current');
       $('#navigation li a[href="#' + id + '"]').addClass('current');
     }
   });
});
```

Also you need to set your current class color as important to make it work

```
.current {
  color: red!important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Everything works except one thing, I want it to highlight a little bit earlier, like, it adds the class but it doesn't consider the height of the nav so I'd click the link and scroll a little more then addclass would happen. How do I fix this? How do I make the highlighting happen a little before it actually hits the top of a section?

Comment: Ok I added var navHeight = $('#navigation').height();
and modify the if statement to if(position >= target - navHeight) 
It works flawlessly. Thanks again!